# firebase current user id

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am getting an error retrieving current user id from my factory/service. Removing this `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` seems to work.
Am I missing something?
Is it possible to get user id from factory?

```
.factory("dataFire", ["$firebaseArray", "$firebaseAuth", "$firebaseObject", function($firebaseArray, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject){
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
var user = $firebaseObject(ref);
return {
    user: user

} }])
```

jsfiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/ken19net/m8qkdrpu/37/

Comment: It is impossible to see what's going wrong from just this code snippet. Is there any way you can reproduce the problem in a **minimal** jsfiddle/jsbin and link that from your question?

Comment: hi frank thanks for the reply. Updated my post with jsfiddle link.I was planning to put all of my database reference to my service.

Answer (score 0):

Your code that attach the listener to the database, runs *before* the user is signed in. Since there is no current user at that point `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` will throw the following error:

> VM603 angular.min.js:118 TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

In future questions please include the error message, as it would've saved us both some time.

The solution is to attach the listener *after* the user has been authenticated:

```
app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseAuth, myService) {

  $scope.signIn = function() {
    $firebaseAuth().$signInAnonymously().then(function(user) {
      var ref = firebase.database().ref("test/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
    });
  };

});
```

Note that running your code like above will create a new anonymous user account every time the user loads the page. If that is not what you want, use an auth state listener:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("test/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
  }
});
```

See the [documentation on getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Answer (score 0):

I might of had a similar problem. This might help.

```
if (firebase.auth().currentUser !== null) {
        console.log("user id: " + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);

        var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("users/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);

        var syncUserObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
        syncUserObject.$bindTo($scope, "data");

    } else {
        console.log("No user currently logged in");
    }
```

if all else fails then just JSON.stringify(Object ,null, 2);